# Msocaf Report error in memory management /spdispose check

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a piece of code on which when I am running MSoCaf, its giving a error under memory management/spdisposechaeck. But there is no 
particular description of error and its saying "Call to Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.get_Item and no variable to catch return value" as resolution. Can anyone please tell me what would be the expected cause of the error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some poc I found the answer.

rootsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url;

this type of line where a site is opened by not disposed properly msocaf gives the above mentioned error.